# A question edit that invalidated an answer and its review is no longer in the queue

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A broad [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/86662/14897) was asked, and [its review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/57489) queue was [invalidated by Edit](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3931/14897).

The edit (not OP's) also invalidated the oldest answer, which as we know, is [not cool](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3103/14897).

<s>I've rolled back the edit, but the current issue is that my vote to close due to being too broad will probably be pointless, since as mentioned, the queue was invalidated.</s>

Should the question be closed? Closed *and* Edit Locked? Something else? I mentioned "locked" because if it is narrowed down in the future and gets reopened, that **would *still invalidate*** one or more of the answers.

Comment: personally, I disagree with your rollback. the edit was done with the intent of avoiding the closure by making the question less broad and within the parameters of the site, it was clearly in the interest of the asker, that could have asked the second question separately. not interfering with the intent does not mean not helping

Comment: @Federico: I think the timeline matters: the removed question was *already* answered https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/86662/timeline -- the answer was then downvoted, and flagged LQ.

Comment: I know about that answer. that makes the case for not answering hastily, not to edit questions with the intent of closing them instead of leaving them open

Comment: @Federico: I trust your judgement in balancing this issue if you wish to revert my rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the editor, I've considered my options. As the question clearly violated the rule against 2-in-1, it was doomed to get closed as is.

The second half of the question, by itself, would've been a [duplicate](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=statically%20unstable%20aircraft).

The first part of the question (what happens if an aircraft is sometimes unstable) still made sense for the second to be answered as an implied question. It's unfortunate that this invalidated an answer, but the only way to salvage the question appeared to be to remove the part that was answered.

In my opinion, the best thing to do in such situation is to do the edit, but explain it in comments to both the question and the answer, so that both parties are notified. (I've missed the latter part, done that now).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I agree with you that leaving a note is probably the best option.